# Compiling NeHe (or other 32 bit oriented) examples on Linux-64

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, 64-bit

I have multiple NeHe OpenGL tutorials, they are Linux/GLX oriented, I have Linux 64 bit. The problem is that many tutorials assume 32 bit system. In particular they will fail to load a file because `sizeof(int)` is not 4 (32 bits) and `sizeof(short)` is not 2 (16 bits). Is there a way to tell the compiler to make `int` 32 bit? OR how do I compile and run the examples without reinstalling the OS?

Comment: That is downright poor design. If the tutorials used `GLint` and `GLshort` instead this never would have been an issue. Those are guaranteed to have a specific bit-width (32-bit and 16-bit respectively) on any system that implements OpenGL. The alternative and even more common approach is to use standard types such as `uint32_t` (C99) or even something nasty like `DWORD` (ancient Windows standard type that is always 32-bit) when file structures are being established.

Comment: That said, targeting 64-bit Linux generally *does not* change the size of `short` or `int`. It mostly affects larger integral types like `long`, and data pointers such as `void*`, types large enough to store contiguous address ranges such as `intptr_t`, etc.

Comment: I don't know why you expect that `sizeof (int) == 32`.  The `sizeof` operator returns units of `char` objects, not bits.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux, and using `gcc` (and running with `multilib`) you can pass the `-m32` option to `gcc` which will compile for the "32-bit" architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Man page on [GCC](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) tells,

```
-m32
-m64
```

> Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment. The 32-bit environment sets int, 
>   long and pointer to 32 bits and generates code that runs on any i386 system. The 
>   64-bit environment sets int to 32 bits and long and pointer to 64 bits and 
>   generates code for AMD 's x86-64 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the `LoadBMP()` function is the only problem in the tutorial examples. Here I post the modified version of this function so that you can run the examples. Just replace `LoadBMP` with this:

```
/* simple loader for 24bit bitmaps (data is in rgb-format) */
int loadBMP(char *filename, textureImage *texture)
{
    FILE *file;
/*    unsigned short int bfType;
    long int bfOffBits;
    short int biPlanes;
    short int biBitCount;
    long int biSizeImage;
    int i;
    unsigned char temp;*/
    uint16_t bfType;
    int32_t bfOffBits;
    short int biPlanes;
    short int biBitCount;
    long int biSizeImage;
    int i;
    unsigned char temp;
    /* make sure the file is there and open it read-only (binary) */
    if ((file = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found : %s\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    if(!fread(&bfType, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, file))
    {
        printf("Error reading file!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /* check if file is a bitmap */
    if (bfType != 19778)
    {
        printf("Not a Bitmap-File!\n");
        return 0;
    }        
    /* get the file size */
    /* skip file size and reserved fields of bitmap file header */
    fseek(file, 8, SEEK_CUR);
    /* get the position of the actual bitmap data */
    if (!fread(&bfOffBits, sizeof(int32_t), 1, file))
    {
        printf("Error reading file!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Data at Offset: %ld\n", bfOffBits);
    /* skip size of bitmap info header */
    fseek(file, 4, SEEK_CUR);
    /* get the width of the bitmap */
    fread(&texture->width, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    printf("Width of Bitmap: %d\n", texture->width);
    /* get the height of the bitmap */
    fread(&texture->height, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    printf("Height of Bitmap: %d\n", texture->height);
    /* get the number of planes (must be set to 1) */
    fread(&biPlanes, sizeof(short int), 1, file);
    if (biPlanes != 1)
    {
        printf("Error: number of Planes not 1!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /* get the number of bits per pixel */
    if (!fread(&biBitCount, sizeof(short int), 1, file))
    {
        printf("Error reading file!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Bits per Pixel: %d\n", biBitCount);
    if (biBitCount != 24)
    {
        printf("Bits per Pixel not 24\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /* calculate the size of the image in bytes */
    biSizeImage = texture->width * texture->height * 3;
    printf("Size of the image data: %ld\n", biSizeImage);
    texture->data = malloc(biSizeImage);
    /* seek to the actual data */
    fseek(file, bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);
    if (!fread(texture->data, biSizeImage, 1, file))
    {
        printf("Error loading file!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /* swap red and blue (bgr -> rgb) */
    for (i = 0; i < biSizeImage; i += 3)
    {
        temp = texture->data[i];
        texture->data[i] = texture->data[i + 2];
        texture->data[i + 2] = temp;
    }
    return 1;
}
```